# Parametrize Garbage Collection for Weblogic to increase performance

Tags: performance, garbage-collection, weblogic, weblogic12c

first let me tell u about the system that i have a problem with:
Clustered WebLogic Server:

- Weblogic Version 12.1
- 4 Nodes
- Each Node has 8 CPUs
- Each Node has 48 GB RAM

We have an application that inserts data into our DB using this Server. Average speed is creation and saving of 20 Object Files  per minute.
After 1 hour of working almost perfectly, it begins to decrease in performance and after another 1 hour, the whole RAM is Full, even weblogic consloe does not respond in this situation. No more requests is addressed and none of the requests of our Bean is answered.

We had a guess that our problem is with GC and it does not free memory properly.
The following are the configurations we used for Weblogic GC( Java VM Options):

> -Xms40g 
>   -Xmx40g -Dweblogic.MaxMessageSize=20000000 
>   -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions 
>   -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32m 
>   -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200
>   -XX:G1NewSizePercent=10
>   -XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=60
>   -XX:ParallelGCThreads=5
>   -XX:ConcGCThreads=1
>   -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=45
>   -XX:G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent=85
>   -XX:G1HeapWastePercent=5
>   -XX:G1MixedGCCountTarget=8
>   -XX:G1OldCSetRegionThresholdPercent=10
>   -XX:G1ReservePercent=10

What do you suggest for our parameterization?

Comment: Sure: remove all of these options. Then, if you still have problems, add only options whose meaning you understand. Besides that, if you have a memory leak, no option will change that. You have to fix your code.

Comment: @Holger at the first try there were no options at all and we had same problem. So I tried to find something useful and my guess was about GC and these options. for now I am struggling to find proper options with good values. thanks for your comment

Comment: In other words, none of these options helped you. As I suspected. There is no magic option that can solve your memory leak. But you are in a comfortable situation, as your problem is reproducible. So you only have to run your application for 1½ hours, take a heap dump and analyze it.

Comment: @Holger you were absolutely right! those options were bullshit at all. we have found that in our weblogic we have huge amount of pooled connections! about 70000 connections. :(